# Nmap Logs Question

Tags: 15.04, security, nmap

I recently did an Nmap scan of my network with the ZenMap GUI tool on my Ubuntu install and I got a weird scan result; well in my opinion anyways..

Even though I am using Ubuntu 15.04, for my host, I get the following results:

```
Device Type: AXIS Linux 2.6.X, Linux 2.6.X, ZyXEL embedded
OS CPE: cpe:/h:axis:210a_network_camera cpe:/
h:axis:211_network_camera cpe:/
o:axis:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/
o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/
o:google:android:2.2 cpe:/h:zyxel:nsa-210
OS details: AXIS 210A or 211 Network Camera (Linux 2.6.17), 
Linux 2.6.14 - 2.6.34, Linux 2.6.17, Linux 2.6.17 (Mandriva), Android
2.2 (Linux 2.6), ZyXEL NSA-210 NAS device
Network Distance: 0 hops
```

I also got a *warning* from the log that the results may be *unreliable* however, it's weird I got these results since the other hosts that were detected in the scan were *correct*.

My question now are these results normal or should I be alarmed since I do not have any of those indicated in my logs being used.

Comment: Which version of `nmap` do you have? and what options have you used with `nmap` for scanning?

Comment: My nmap version is 6.47 however I am using the gui version zenmap. The commands I used was nmap -sV -T4 -O -F --version-light 10.10.10.*

Comment: I've tried nmap -sV -T4 -O -d 10.10.10.* as well with same results

Comment: Funny thing about `zenmap` which you say below.  It's not always as reliable as the nmap tool being called from the command line.  Call your same command directly from the command line with `nmap` and not `zenmap` and see if you get different output.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you for the comment but when I used your advice I got the same results in nmap.

Answer (score 0):

<del>What command did you typed in to get this output ?</del>

<del>May the `man nmap` can help you to fix your command if you don't want to share it.</del>

To get to know your ubuntu version use

```
lsb_release -a
```

The output should be like

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

To check your nmap version type

```
nmap -V
```

Just to compare:
When I type your command `nmap -sV -T4 -O -d 10.10.10` I get (I skipped the scanning part)

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-17 20:51 CEST
PORTS: Using top 1000 ports found open (TCP:1000, UDP:0, SCTP:0)
--------------- Timing report ---------------
  hostgroups: min 1, max 100000
  rtt-timeouts: init 500, min 100, max 1250
  max-scan-delay: TCP 10, UDP 1000, SCTP 10
  parallelism: min 0, max 0
  max-retries: 6, host-timeout: 0
  min-rate: 0, max-rate: 0
---------------------------------------------
NSE: Using Lua 5.2.
NSE: Script Arguments seen from CLI: 
NSE: Loaded 29 scripts for scanning.
Initiating Ping Scan at 20:51
Scanning 256 hosts [4 ports/host]
```

Comment: My lsb_release -a response was the same as above. Please check the comment above for the cmd I used for the scan.

Comment: thanks. I added my ouput of your command for comparing. I'm using nmap 6.47 which version are you using ?

Comment: My version is the same as yours however I am using the GUI version Zenmap. Thanks for showing your log results but what should I look for in this comparison? Also which cmd did you use because in the above comment I had two.

Comment: Ahh! sorry. I used the second one. I realy do not know why your are getting this error

Comment: I don't know either :/ any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Nmap covers misidentified hosts in the [online documentation](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-unidentified.html), but here is the short version:

1. Make sure you are using [the latest Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html).
2. Get better scan conditions. Nmap will give unreliable results if you are more than 5 network hops away, if you are scanning with `-T5`, or if there were no open or no closed TCP ports discovered.
3. [Send a correction](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-unidentified.html#osdetect-wrong) if Nmap still guesses wrong. This improves the database for everyone.